# Testing function that returns an interface

Tags: go

I'm having difficulty writing test for the case below.

I'm able to write test for "helper" with a mock object that only implements the functions that used by myself.

How do I write test code for the function 'new' using a mock object without mocking functions C(), D()?

It could be that the other package is written poorly that it should not return an Interface but rather the actual struct?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    New()
}

func New() {
    new(NewFromEnvironment)
}

type newTopology func()(Interface,error)

// new is non-exposed simply used for testing purpose.
func new(newTopology newTopology) {
  t,_ :=  newTopology()
  helper(t)
}

// I need to call only A and B
type topologyInterface interface {
    A() string
    B() string
}

func helper(topology topologyInterface) {
    s1 := topology.A()
    s2 := topology.B()
    fmt.Println(s1 + "," + s2)
}

// Below are from other package named "topology".
// I have no control to the code below.

type Interface interface {
    A() string
    B() string
    C() string
    D() string
    //... more
}

func NewFromEnvironment() (Interface, error) {
    return P{}, nil
}

type P struct{}

func (p P) A() string {
    return "A"
}

func (p P) B() string {
    return "B"
}

func (p P) C() string {
    return "C"
}

func (p P) D() string {
    return "D"
}

// more...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but it looks to me like you want a mock object which implements `Interface`, but you don't want to duplicate the code from `C` and `D`. Maybe create a struct `MockP` which embeds `P`? Then `MockP` inherits all the methods of `P`, but you can shadow `A` and `B` with your own mock implementations.

Comment: @MihaiTodor yes, I don't want to mock the functions that I don't need. Among the 10 functions that interface has, I only used 2.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I tried your solution, it works well.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that my suggestion helped. I posted a detailed example as an answer.

Comment: It sounds like it is poorly designed. "Accept abstractions, return concretions" - i.e., parameters should be interface types, returned values should be concrete types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a struct `MockP` which embeds `P`. Then `MockP` inherits all the methods of `P`, but you can shadow `A()` and `B()` with your own mock implementations. Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Interface interface {
    A()
    B()
}

type P struct {
}

func (p P) A() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}


func (p P) B() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}

type MockP struct {
    P
}

// Shadow P's B() method
func (p MockP) B() {
    fmt.Println("Mock B")
}

func main() {
    var p Interface = MockP{}
    p.A()
    p.B()
}
```

Output:

```
A
Mock B
```

Comment: I actually embedded the interface.

Comment: That also works, but you'll get a panic if the code happens to call any method that hasn't been mocked.